# How to clone a dataset to another BigQuery project

Tags: dataset, view, google-bigquery

Suppose you have a Google-BigQuery project per Client. Now a new Client is coming aboard. What is the best procedure to clone a project, a dataset or an object like a view to a new project?

I have a dataset with a set of views containing analytics logic. It would be great if I could copy those views to the new project.

Thanks

Comment: BigQuery just launch a new feature to copy dataset across project and region. Check out the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets). The feature only copy normal table and partition table, but doesn't copy view yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as an option - you can have script that

- take list of all views in your master dataset with [Tables: list API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/list)
- loops through all views (check [type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/list#tables.type) property) in list response  and

  - for each view read with [Tables: get API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get) view [definition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#view) and other relevant properties and
  - then create with [Tables: insert API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/insert) respective view in new dataset

Should be pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

We had similar requirement to transfer all or selective Views and Table definitions from One Big Query project to another per Dataset level, Hence have coded in-house to transfer all/selective tables Schemas and Views Definitions using Biq Query APIs. It is shallow cloning(no table data transferred) to destination Big Query project.

Feel free to ask for code example if you still need it. I will be happy to share my Java Code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on Mikhail Berlyant's answer. After creating the new dataset:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery.table import Table


ORIGINAL_PROJECT_ID = "original-project-id"
NEW_PROJECT_ID = "new-project-id"
ORIGINAL_DATASET_ID = "original-dataset-id"
NEW_DATASET_ID = "new-dataset-id"

client = bigquery.Client(project=ORIGINAL_PROJECT_ID)

tables_list = [
    table
    for table in client.list_tables(dataset=ORIGINAL_DATASET_ID)
    if table.table_type == "VIEW"
]

tables = [client.get_table(table) for table in tables_list]

for table in tables:
    new_table = Table(f"{NEW_PROJECT_ID}.{NEW_DATASET_ID}.{table.table_id}")
    new_table.view_query = table.view_query
    client.create_table(new_table)
```