# Proper Design of Prod and Non Prod for Big Query and Deployment Management

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am looking for some information related to Deployment... [Not Deployment manager]

After I have designed my BigQuery tables Schema and if I want to use the same model to move to a different project which is considered as Production environment, how should I move.

Is it like saving the schema from non prod project and deploying or creating in production project? Is this approach correct? or is this model of non production and production project versioning is that good?

I am not able to find any resource related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you are trying to do. If you have a look in the [BigQuery quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quickstart-web-ui), you will see that there is not a "deployment" for BigQuery. Consider BigQuery like a tables store.

If you want to have a [backup](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations), you can export the data to Cloud Storage in several formats (as for example CSV).

If you want to exactly duplicate your project, follow this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy-table). To do it programmatically, follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490166/how-to-clone-a-dataset-to-another-bigquery-project), written by a Google Developer.